# Android: from surfaceview back to the menu

Tags: android, layout, surfaceview, void

I am making a simple game in which I draw a set of bitmaps on a Canvas on SurfaceView.
Now in my main activity I have a LinearLayout where I have designed a button.
In the `onClick()` of this button I write:

```
setContentView(new surfaceviewclass(this));
```

it works fine. It opens the SurfaceView and I play the game etc.
But I want to see the button again where I started from I mean when the game is over I want the menu to reappear..
I have already tried calling the void like

```
main.menu();
```

but the app crashes..
please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new activity class and write this in onCreate() method of it

```
setContentView(new surfaceviewclass(this));
```

and in the previous activity create an Intent and start this new activity when button is clicked

```
e.g ....// onclick method of btn on old activity
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(OldClass.this, NewClass.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    ....
```

Comment: i want to go from te surfaceview to te menu...
i can go from menu to surfaceview..
want to go to menu from surface view

Comment: ok so you should get a Context object from your MainActivity and then when you want to go back to menu just put this line on the gameover state

    context.setContentView(_yourlayoutid_);